# Php app that shows how many facebook notifications does user have

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, api

I'm creating interface for my Chromium based application, and I've got a problem. I'd like it to show number of my facebook notifications (these white numbers in red rectangles) directly on my website. Is it possible? I couldn't find nothing about that on google.

It should look like: Patrick have 5 new notifications.

**EDIT:**

Now I've got this:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{notification-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

how to echo this notification-id on webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Facebook Graph API /user/notifications/ for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/notifications

Comment: But before you use that you should read what is required to get that permissions approved at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-manage_notifications